# Setting HtmlTag decorator for form element

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm learning how to use decorators in Zend Framework. I've go really simple code:

```
$this->addElement('text', 'wybor', array(
    'label' => 'Wybierz',
    'multiOptions' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three'),
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'td')),
    ),
));
```

but it seems that HtmlTag doesn't work in this case - form element isn't surrounded with  tags.

Am I doing something wrong here? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: try this $this->addElement('text', 'wybor', array(
    'label' => 'Wybierz',
    'multiOptions' => array(1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two', 3 => 'Three'),
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        'HtmlTag'=>array('tag' => 'td'),
    ),
));

Comment: @TahirYasin: After that I've go an exception with: "Plugin by name 'Td' was not found in the registry; used paths: Zend_Form_Decorator_: Zend/Form/Decorator/" message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code for more options:

```
$elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array('Errors', array('class' => 'err-msg')),
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'span', 'class' => 'element')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'span')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class'=>'form-row')),
    );
```